# How can I get selenium to interact with fivethirtyeight search bars?

Tags: python, selenium, search

I am working with this website (https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-nba-player-projections/) and trying to automate a search of players. I have a list of players but cannot seem to connect to the correct element. I have tried xpath, id, and css_selector. Below is an example code:

```
driver.get('https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-nba-player-projections/')
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id('player-selectbox')
search_bar.click() 
search_bar.send_keys('lebron james')
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Whichever way I try, I get the following error:

```
Message: element not interactable
```

Below is a link to a screenshot of the box I'm trying to access.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W173Y.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us which exact element you are trying to interact with? Adding a screenshot with an indicator of the search bar will be useful

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver.get("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-nba-player- projections/")
    
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='player name']").click()
    
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='player name']").send_keys('Kyrie Irving')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='player name']").send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

This code works perfectly, the complexity is that it is an autofill type search bar, I found an easy workaround using Keys.ARROW_RIGHT to take care of it

Attaching screenshot below,

[image: pic contains proof of working automation]

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='player name']")
search_bar.click()
search_bar.send_keys('lebron james')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='tt-suggestion tt-selectable']").click()
```

Feel free to replace `time.sleep` with `explicit wait`

Comment: thank you @Anand this works a majority of the time, I catch the random few with exceptions

Comment: I tried this and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get the data directly from the json? Would be far more efficient than Selenium.

```
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# Get Player Slugs from javascript
response = requests.get('https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-nba-player-projections/js/bundle.js')

js = response.text
p = re.compile('{t\.exports=(\[.*}]},{}\])')
result = p.search(js).group(1).rsplit('},{}',1)[0]

result = result.replace('team_abbr', '"team_abbr"')
result = result.replace('name', '"name"')
result = result.replace('full_team', '"full_team"')
result = result.replace('short_team', '"short_team"')
result = result.replace('slug', '"slug"')
result = result.replace(',randable:!1', '')
result = result.replace(',randable:!0', '')

playerSearch = json.loads(result)
df = pd.DataFrame(playerSearch)

players = list(df['name'])
slugs = list(df['slug'])

playerDict = dict(zip(players, slugs))



# Get the Player Data
# You could also make this as a user input

list_of_players = ['lebron james', 'Derik RoSe', 'LEamarkcus Allridge']

data = {}
for player in list_of_players:
    playerMatch = process.extractOne(player, list(playerDict.keys()))[0]
    player_slug = playerDict[playerMatch]

    url = f'https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-nba-player-projections/{player_slug}.json'
    jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
    
    data[playerMatch] = jsonData
    print(f'Returned: {playerMatch}')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Megalina has not specified the use of Python Requests. Megalina wants it to be done with Python Selenium